# ruby - One superclass , 2 subclasses and One common Method - Having an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subclass, mixins, superclass

The following  has Universe(superclass) , Common(module), FlatEarthBelievers(subclass) and RoundEarthBelievers(subclass). There is an error with the output and want to make it work, any pointers?

This is about inheritance and mixins, a scenario where child classes inherit from a common Parent and want to utilise the common methods that are not related to the Parent's behaviour. I want to be able to call the methods from the common module inside the Child class that includes/extends it . I have a confusion in its usage because I want to see those common methods as both class methods and instance methods.

```
 class Universe
      $knowledge = "Universe comprises of galaxies, stars, planets,  steroids, meteoroids, comets, etc"
       def  universe_comprises_of
       puts $knowledge
     end
    end

    ​module Common
      $earth_is = Hash.new
      def init(earth_is)
        $earth_is = earth_is
      end
       def statement
         puts  " Earth is " + $earth_is["attribute"].to_str
       end
    end

    class FlatEarthBelievers < Universe
      include Common
      earth_is = { :attribute => "Flat !" }
      init(earth_is)
    end

    class RoundEarthBelievers < Universe
       include Common
       earth_is = { :attribute => "Round like an Orange!" }
       Common.init(earth_is)
    end

    moron = FlatEarthBelievers.new
    moron.universe_comprises_of
    moron.statement

    sensible_person = RoundEarthBelievers.new
    sensible_person.universe_comprises_of
    sensible_person.statement
```

Comment: Please format your post with a code block per class, detail the error and explain what you want to do, there's some formating errors in the code but I think it's because of your C/P

Comment: FWIW, it is 'un-Ruby-like' to have variable names that start with `$`

Comment: Why? THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT, @instance_variable, local_variable, $global_variable more here

Comment: "There is an error" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @NMPennypacker: It is not just "un-Ruby-like". It is generally un-programming-like to use global variables. Ever.

Comment: I am fairly certain the universe is not comprised of [steroids](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steroid)

Comment: Thank you everyone and "jvillan" in specific. The question was about inheritance and mixins, a scenario where child classes inherit from a common Parent and want to utilise the common methods that are not related to the Parent's behaviour. I wanted to be able to call the methods from the common module inside the Child class that includes/extends it , I had a confusion in its usage because I wanted to see the common methods as both class methods and instance methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things wrong with this code. Set aside the `$` variable issue since that is discussed in the comments to your OP.

To begin with, you do:

```
moron = Flat_earth_believers.new
```

But you don't have any classes named `Flat_earth_believers`. You probably meant `FlatEarthBelievers`.

You `include` the `Common` module, which makes all the methods therein instance methods, but then you try to call them as class methods, here:

```
class FlatEarthBelievers < Universe
  include Common
  earth_is = { :attribute => "Flat!" }
  init(earth_is) # this is calling a class method
end
```

and here:

```
class RoundEarthBelievers < Universe
  include Common
  earth_is = { :attribute => "Round like an Orange!" }
  Common.init(earth_is) # this is calling a class method
end
```

There's other stuff, but you get the idea.

Anyway, I don't really know what you're trying to do, but I think I would just make `Universe` like:

```
class Universe
  KNOWLEDGE = "Universe comprises of galaxies, stars, planets,  steroids, meteoroids, comets, etc"

  def  universe_comprises_of
    puts KNOWLEDGE
  end
end
```

And `Common` like:

```
module Common

  def statement
    puts "Earth is #{self.class::EARTH_IS[:attribute]}"
  end  

end
```

Then `FlatEarthBelievers` like:

```
class FlatEarthBelievers < Universe
  include Common

  EARTH_IS = { :attribute => "Flat!" }
end
```

Then you can do:

```
moron = FlatEarthBelievers.new
moron.universe_comprises_of
 => Universe comprises of galaxies, stars, planets,  steroids, meteoroids, comets, etc
moron.statement
 => Earth is Flat!
```

I will also note that [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag) wishes to say:

> I am one of those Ruby Purists who likes to point out that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. I am perfectly fine, though, with using the term *class method* colloquially, **as long as it is fully understood by all parties that it is a colloquial usage**. In other words, if you *know* that there is no such thing as a class method and that the term "class method" is just short for "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of `Class`", then there is no problem. But otherwise, I have only seen it obstruct understanding.

Let it be fully understood by all parties that the term *class method* is used above in its colloquial sense.

Comment: Thank you everyone and "jvillan" in specific. The question was about inheritance and mixins, a scenario where child classes inherit from a common Parent and want to utilise the common methods that are not related to the Parent's behaviour. I wanted to be able to call the methods from the common module inside the Child class that includes/extends it , I had a confusion in its usage because I wanted to see as both class methods and instance methods.